# Shell script to force carriage return to avoid long lines

Tags: shell, text-formatting

I have to use a tool (namely, Rez) which processes text but does not allow long text lines; I would like to **shorten long lines with a pre-formatting script**.

The script I'm looking for is a simple (darwin/unix) shell script which cuts long lines, for instance inserting a carriage return after the 70th character of the line, if the character is a space (any other idea would work, I thing).

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: To me the task is not clear yet.  You always want to insert a line-feed after the 70th character or only replace a space with the line-feed?  Can you describe this more precise?

Comment: @mvds: indeed, fold or fmt could do it. But fmt fails with "Illegal byte sequence", the file I use is ISO-8859 with special characters :(

Comment: @baruch: darwin/unix, edited.

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger: as you wish. All I don't want to have is very long lines.

Comment: @moala: have you tried to set the correct locale for the character encoding you're formatting?

Comment: What does "ISO-8859 with special characters" mean? Is it 8859 or isn't it, and if so, which 8859?  Run `file` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `fold` utility does the job, with the -s option. Do not forget to set the correct locale setting so that fold does not fail on special characters.

All my thanks to mvds.